# inbound adapter skipping messages

Tags: spring-integration

This is how my configuration looks like

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="files" directory="${lz.dir.${ft}}">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="3000" max-messages-per-poll="3"  />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:bridge input-channel="files" output-channel="sourceFiles" />

<int:channel id="sourceFiles">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor" />
</int:channel>

<int:service-activator  input-channel="sourceFiles" 
                        ref="moveToSource" 
                        method="move" />

<int:aggregator id="filesBuffered" 
                input-channel="sourceFiles"
                output-channel="stagedFiles"
                release-strategy-expression="size() == 10" 
                correlation-strategy-expression="'mes-group'" 
                expire-groups-upon-completion="true" 
                />

<int:channel id="stagedFiles" />

<int:service-activator  input-channel="stagedFiles"
                        ref="moveToStage"   
                        method="move" />

<task:executor id="executor" pool-size="5" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

The idea is to poll a directory every 3 second and emit 3 messages per poll to a dispatcher based on channel to allow asynchronous execution. Messages are then aggregated based on number of messages and then emitted to next service activator. The first service activator places files in source directory and second service activator which gets the aggregated list to move those files to staging directory.

What seems to be happening is that source folder skips some files but the staging folder does gets all the files. My guess is that poller sends the messages to the dispatcher channel but when its thread pool gets full it simply ignores the files but somehow the aggregator still gets all the files. Almost like dispatcher channel skips the first service activator step for files it receives after the thread pool limit has reached but those files are still passed to next channel and thats how they still end up getting processed by the second service activator.

What I would like to do is have the poller resend the files that were rejected by the dispatcher. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't understand what you describe, but by your configuration it looks like:

1. `sourceFiles` channel is point-to-point one. So, only one subscriber at a time can get message from that channel.
2. But you have two subscribers - service-activator and aggregator
3. By default `dispatcher` uses `RoundRobinLoadBalancingStrategy`. That means, that first message will be processed by first subscriber, the second one - by second subscriberб and so on, like relay.
4. So, if you want to have a **sequential**, there is need to subscribe aggregator to the outbound-channel of `moveToSource` service-activator and return from `move` method the same payload. In your case `File`.

If it isn't your case, so provide, please, correct config or explain your use-case.
Now it is confused, sorry.

HTH